# Use Both Active Directory and internal user in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, jenkins-plugins

We use Jenkins and Active Directory plugin for authentication.
For some reason, I need to add a specific account in Jenkins but not in Active Directory.
Is it possible to use both Active Directory and internal user ?

If it's impossible, I think I can modify the plugin to add an account in it.
I know it's not a good idea, but we need this function.

I think it's in ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.java's retrieveUser() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Jenkins deployed to an app server and the app server supports your use case, you can use the "Delegate to servlet container" option in the Security Realm.

You might be able to utilize the [Script Security Realm Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Realm)